Maximum flow - Dinic's algorithm - quesion

Lemma 1. The distances from  $s$  to each vertex don't decrease after each iteration, i. e.
$level_{i+1}[v] \ge level_i[v]$ .
Proof. Fix a phase   $i$  and a vertex  $v$ . Consider any shortest
path  $P$  from  $s$  to  $v$  in   $G_{i+1}^R$ . The length of  $P$ 
equals  $level_{i+1}[v]$ . Note that   $G_{i+1}^R$  can only contain
edges from   $G_i^R$  and back edges for edges from   $G_i^R$ . If
$P$  has no back edges for   $G_i^R$ , then  $level_{i+1}[v] \ge
level_i[v]$  because  $P$  is also a path in   $G_i^R$ . Now, suppose
that  $P$  has at least one back edge. Let the first such edge be
$(u, w)$ .Then  $level_{i+1}[u] \ge level_i[u]$  (because of the
first case). The edge  $(u, w)$  doesn't belong to   $G_i^R$ , so the
edge  $(w, u)$  was affected by the blocking flow on the previous
iteration. It means that  $level_i[u] = level_i[w] + 1$ . Also,
$level_{i+1}[w] = level_{i+1}[u] + 1$ . From these two equa

Maximum flow - Dinic's algorithm
Why The edge  $(u, w)$  doesn't belong to  
$G_i^R$ , so the edge  $(w, u)$  was affected by the blocking flow on the previous iteration?

[cs.se] seems better for this, both due to what you want and due to LaTeX support.
